# script not working on my android browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile, browser

I use wordpress to make a site and made a script where people can select a radio button and than one more selection shows up. But the script is not working on android internet browser what did I do wrong

Here is the form:

```
<form id='form-id' action="http://trainingzuid.nl/wp-content/php/mail.php" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input id='pt' name='test' type='radio' /> personal training</td>
  <td><input id='gt' name='test' type='radio' /> group training</td>
  <td><input id='bt' name='test' type='radio' /> both</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='pur' style='display:none'>Purpose:</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='gf' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> general fitness</input></div></td>
<td><div id='lw' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> losing weight</div></td>
<td><div id='bt1' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> both</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='kb' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> kickboksen</input></div></td>
<td><div id='b' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> boksen</div></td>
<td><div id='kkb' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> kids kickbosen</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='bf' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> ballet fitness</input></div></td>
<td><div id='ch' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> cross hit</div></td>
<td><div id='t6' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> training 6</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='t7' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> training 7</input></div></td>
<td><div id='t8' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> training 8</div></td>
<td><div id='t9' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> training 9</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First and last name"></p></td>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail adress"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phonenumber"></p></td>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="message" placeholder="additional message"></p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></center>
  <center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and the js code:

```
<script>
$('#form-id').change(function() {
    if ($('#pt').attr('checked')) {
        $('#pur').show();
        $('#gf').show();
        $('#lw').show();
        $('#bt1').show();
    } else {
        $('#pur').hide();
        $('#gf').hide();
        $('#lw').hide();
        $('#bt1').hide();
    }
    if ($('#gt').attr('checked')) {
        $('#pur').show();
        $('#kb').show();
        $('#b').show();
        $('#kkb').show();
        $('#bf').show();
        $('#ch').show();
        $('#t6').show();
        $('#t7').show();
        $('#t8').show();
        $('#t9').show();
    } else {
        $('#pur1').hide();
        $('#kb').hide();
        $('#b').hide();
        $('#kkb').hide();
        $('#bf').hide();
        $('#ch').hide();
        $('#t6').hide();
        $('#t7').hide();
        $('#t8').hide();
        $('#t9').hide();
    }
    if ($('#bt').attr('checked')) {
        $('#pur').show();
        $('#gf').show();
        $('#lw').show();
        $('#bt1').show();
    } else {
        $('#pur2').hide();
        $('#gf1').hide();
        $('#lw1').hide();
        $('#bt12').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

I found lot of scripts but this was the only working one on my theme with wordpress.

THNX for all the help!!

Comment: what an earth is this lol :))) can't you refactor your code first?

Comment: what errors do you have in the console??

Comment: not what's "not working", but you could try `is(':checked')` but I'm voting to close as **Questions without a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I am new to stockoverflow not use it much. don't understand how it works here. But the script works when you press a readio button the next radio buttons show up. on all browsers it works but not on my internet browser on my android phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome browser on the Android device you should get the same results as the desktop version. Try other device, browser and see if you get the same problem.